# Expand column to fit screen width

Tags: dart, flutter

So i like to figure out how to make Card widget become full width in flutter, basically it only expand its width based on its child, i want it to fit the screen, the task fairly simple but im having a really hard time achieving that, in my scaffold basically it contain two card, and have some text in it, the card only expand to the size of the end of the text, i want the card to be full width, how do i achieve this?

I expect it the card to be full width of the screen, but the card only wrap the children text widget

Comment: in your -`Column` - add - `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,`

Comment: just what i was looking for, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the `Column` in a `Container` widget and set it's width to `double.infinity`

This way you'll save some lines of code.

Example Code:

```
Container(
  width : double.infinity,
  child: Column([...])
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            // flex:3,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                color: Colors.cyan,
                child: Text('1'),
              )//Container
          ),//Expanded         
        ],
      )//column
```

this should do the trick

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: new Card(child: Text("This Card is Expanded to full width"),),
            )
          ],
        )
```

Comment: I see we can expand container too with double.infinity...thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can get the screen width with [MediaQuery](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html)

```
final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
```

Comment: I can see i might these for future more complex apps...thank you for your help